# The text is cutting when converting the html page to pdf using jspdf and html2canvas

Tags: jspdf, html2canvas, html2pdf

I am having code as below

```
<HTML>

<HEAD>
    <TITLE>jsPDF HTML Example with html2canvas for Multiple Pages PDF</TITLE>
    <style>
        #doc-target {
            font-family: sans-serif;
            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
            color: #000;
            line-height: 1.6em;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

       #outer {
  padding: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
    </style>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
    <div id="container">
        <p>
            <button class="btn" onclick="generatePdf()">Download PDF</button>
        </p>
        <div id="outer">
            <div id="doc-target">
                <h1>jsPDF HTML Example</h1>
                <div id="lipsum">
                   <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-8 col-sx-12">
                        <div class="row">
                              <div class="col-md-4 ">
                                    <label for=""><strong>Full Name</strong> </label>  
                                    <p class="ng-binding">sandeep</p> 
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-md-4 ">
                                    <label for=""><strong>Marital Status</strong> </label>  
                                    <p class="ng-binding">SINGLE</p> 
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-md-4 ">
                                    <label for=""><strong>Phone Number</strong> </label>  
                                    <p class="ng-binding">8798798798</p> 
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-md-4 ">
                                    <label for=""><strong>Date of Birth</strong> </label>  
                                    <p class="ng-binding">10/10/2004</p> 
                              </div>
                          
                        </div>
               </div>
                    <p>1. All the
                        particulars/details filled in/provided in the Electronic Customer Application Form ("EAF")
                        bearing the above mentioned Reference Number have been entered by me/us. I verify and
                        confirm that
                        all the information and particulars entered/recorded in the EAF are true and correct and I
                        have not
                        withheld any information required for opening the Instant Current Account ("Current
                        Account").</p>
                        <p>1. All the
                        particulars/details filled in/provided in the Electronic Customer Application Form ("EAF")
                        bearing the above mentioned Reference Number have been entered by me/us. I verify and
                        confirm that
                        all the information and particulars entered/recorded in the EAF are true and correct and I
                        have not
                        withheld any information required for opening the Instant Current Account ("Current
                        Account").</p>
                        <p>1. All the
                        particulars/details filled in/provided in the Electronic Customer Application Form ("EAF")
                        bearing the above mentioned Reference Number have been entered by me/us. I verify and
                        confirm that
                        all the information and particulars entered/recorded in the EAF are true and correct and I
                        have not
                        withheld any information required for opening the Instant Current Account ("Current
                        Account").</p>
                        <p>1. All the
                        particulars/details filled in/provided in the Electronic Customer Application Form ("EAF")
                        bearing the above mentioned Reference Number have been entered by me/us. I verify and
                        confirm that
                        all the information and particulars entered/recorded in the EAF are true and correct and I
                        have not
                        withheld any information required for opening the Instant Current Account ("Current
                        Account").</p>
                        <p>1. All the
                        particulars/details filled in/provided in the Electronic Customer Application Form ("EAF")
                        bearing the above mentioned Reference Number have been entered by me/us. I verify and
                        confirm that
                        all the information and particulars entered/recorded in the EAF are true and correct and I
                        have not
                        withheld any information required for opening the Instant Current Account ("Current
                        Account").</p>
                        <p>1. All the
                        particulars/details filled in/provided in the Electronic Customer Application Form ("EAF")
                        bearing the above mentioned Reference Number have been entered by me/us. I verify and
                        confirm that
                        all the information and particulars entered/recorded in the EAF are true and correct and I
                        have not
                        withheld any information required for opening the Instant Current Account ("Current
                        Account").</p>
                        <p>1. All the
                        particulars/details filled in/provided in the Electronic Customer Application Form ("EAF")
                        bearing the above mentioned Reference Number have been entered by me/us. I verify and
                        confirm that
                        all the information and particulars entered/recorded in the EAF are true and correct and I
                        have not
                        withheld any information required for opening the Instant Current Account ("Current
                        Account").</p>
                        <p>1. All the
                        particulars/details filled in/provided in the Electronic Customer Application Form ("EAF")
                        bearing the above mentioned Reference Number have been entered by me/us. I verify and
                        confirm that
                        all the information and particulars entered/recorded in the EAF are true and correct and I
                        have not
                        withheld any information required for opening the Instant Current Account ("Current
                        Account").</p>
                        <p>1. All the
                        particulars/details filled in/provided in the Electronic Customer Application Form ("EAF")
                        bearing the above mentioned Reference Number have been entered by me/us. I verify and
                        confirm that
                        all the information and particulars entered/recorded in the EAF are true and correct and I
                        have not
                        withheld any information required for opening the Instant Current Account ("Current
                        Account").</p>
                        <p>1. All the
                        particulars/details filled in/provided in the Electronic Customer Application Form ("EAF")
                        bearing the above mentioned Reference Number have been entered by me/us. I verify and
                        confirm that
                        all the information and particulars entered/recorded in the EAF are true and correct and I
                        have not
                        withheld any information required for opening the Instant Current Account ("Current
                        Account").</p>
                        <p>1. All the
                        particulars/details filled in/provided in the Electronic Customer Application Form ("EAF")
                        bearing the above mentioned Reference Number have been entered by me/us. I verify and
                        confirm that
                        all the information and particulars entered/recorded in the EAF are true and correct and I
                        have not
                        withheld any information required for opening the Instant Current Account ("Current
                        Account").</p>
                        <p>1. All the
                        particulars/details filled in/provided in the Electronic Customer Application Form ("EAF")
                        bearing the above mentioned Reference Number have been entered by me/us. I verify and
                        confirm that
                        all the information and particulars entered/recorded in the EAF are true and correct and I
                        have not
                        withheld any information required for opening the Instant Current Account ("Current
                        Account").</p>
                       
                        
                    
                   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.5.1/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/1.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"
        integrity="sha512-BNaRQnYJYiPSqHHDb58B0yaPfCu+Wgds8Gp/gU33kqBtgNS4tSPHuGibyoeqMV/TJlSKda6FXzoEyYGjTe+vXA=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

    <script>

        // https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/configuration
        // https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-html.html#~html
        // https://artskydj.github.io/jsPDF/docs/jsPDF.html
        window.jsPDF = window.jspdf.jsPDF;
        function generatePdf() {
            let jsPdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
            var htmlElement = document.getElementById('doc-target');
            // you need to load html2canvas (and dompurify if you pass a string to html)
            const opt = {
                callback: function (jsPdf) {
                    jsPdf.save("Test.pdf");
                    // to open the generated PDF in browser window
                    // window.open(jsPdf.output('bloburl'));
                },
                margin: [50,50,50,50],
                autoPaging: 'text',
                html2canvas: {
                    allowTaint: true,
                    dpi: 300,
                    letterRendering: true,
                    logging: false,
                    scale: .6
                }
            };

            jsPdf.html(htmlElement, opt);
        }
    </script>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

But my issue is after generating into pdf the text toward right corner is breaking somewhere and few words are missing from the next line. Kindly help to how to set the functionality for this one.
I have tried **html2pdf** library but the facing issue with the file size is becoming large. My pdf might consists more than 5 page.

Comment: @KJ thanks for the suggestion and it worked for me but the generated pdf is around 1.4 MB is there any way to reduce the file size to 500 kb. Kindly help me

Comment: @KJ unable to open files provided.

Comment: We are unable open the link the link u have provided seems transfer.sh is restricted India. If possible can u use wetransfer

Comment: @kj thanks for the files but may i know how did u compressed the files. I mean the code snippet will help me to compress these kind of the files